# Spring Data JPA Audit Information on ManyToMany JoinTables

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring Data JPA to provide auditing information to all entities by implementing a common base class.

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class EntityBase {  
    @CreatedDate
    private Date createdDate;

    @CreatedBy
    private String createdBy;

    @LastModifiedDate
    private Date lastModifiedDate;

    @LastModifiedBy
    private String lastModifiedBy;

//setters and getters omitted   
}
```

This works and saves the correct information to the database.

Unfortunatelly, this doesn't add that information to the Join Tables as they are not modelled as entities and not implementing that common base class.

Is there some possiblity to get the audit information also saved to the join tables? Or do I have to model all of Join Tables as Entities?

Comment: join tables you mean something like entityA which is in a onetomany to entityb and when you do a save on entityA, the entityBase component gets saved for entityA but not for entityB?  

And can you give some additional informaiton about the endgame here? Based on your need you might reconsider going with .@MappedSuperclass and instead using .@Inheritence...

Comment: This is the problem I am facing. Is there any solution? @John

Comment: @ilovejavaAJ: Honestly, I've never found a solution using spring data. However, as state in the question you could explicitly model the join tables as entities.

Comment: @John join tables are already entities but still having the same problem. Do you have sample code mapping for reference.